# How add a function in openERP 7?

Tags: python, function, field, odoo

I was trying create a new module in openERP version 7.  In my class I have this code :

```
_columns = {
'hour_from' : fields.float('Work from', required=True),
    'hour_to' : fields.float("Work to", required=True),
     'totalhour': fields.function(_total, method=True, string='Total Attendance', multi="_total"),
}
```

I don't find any solution to add a function in my class. The function which I need it return the sum of `hour_from` and `hour_to`. Can anyone help?

I try this code before declaring my _columns :

```
def _total(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):

  res = {}

    res['totalhour'] = hour_from + hour_to

return res
```

When I restart the server I receive this error:

```
No handler found.
```

**(Update from other post)**

Well this is my code:

```
def _total(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
res = {}
for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
    res['totalhour'] = record.hour_from + record.hour_to
return res

class hr_analytic_timesheet(osv.osv):
_name = "hr.analytic.timesheet"
_inherit = "hr.analytic.timesheet"


_columns = {
'hour_from' : fields.float('Work from', required=True, help="Start and End time of working.", select=True),
    'hour_to' : fields.float("Work to", required=True),

     'totalhour' : fields.function(_total, type='float', method=True, string='Total Hour'),
}

hr_analytic_timesheet()
```

My xml :

```
 <record id="view_ov_perf_timesheet_line_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">hr.analytic.timesheet.tree</field>
        <field name="model">hr.analytic.timesheet</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_timesheet.hr_timesheet_line_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
                  <field name="unit_amount" position="replace">

                    <field name="hour_from" widget="float_time" string="Heure début"/>
                    <field name="hour_to" widget="float_time" string="Heure fin" />
                     <field name="totalhour"  widget="float_time"/>

                   </field>

        </field>
    </record>
```

When I want to add or edit a line, I have this error:

```
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130205-000102\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\orm.py", line 3729, in _read_flat
KeyError: 53
```

can you help mee pleese

---

wel this is my code:

```
def _total(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
res = {}
for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
    res['totalhour'] = record.hour_from + record.hour_to
return res

class hr_analytic_timesheet(osv.osv):
_name = "hr.analytic.timesheet"
_inherit = "hr.analytic.timesheet"


_columns = {
'hour_from' : fields.float('Work from', required=True, help="Start and End time of working.", select=True),
    'hour_to' : fields.float("Work to", required=True),

     'totalhour' : fields.function(_total, type='float', method=True, string='Total Hour'),
}

hr_analytic_timesheet()
```

My xml :

```
 <record id="view_ov_perf_timesheet_line_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">hr.analytic.timesheet.tree</field>
        <field name="model">hr.analytic.timesheet</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_timesheet.hr_timesheet_line_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
                  <field name="unit_amount" position="replace">

                    <field name="hour_from" widget="float_time" string="Heure début"/>
                    <field name="hour_to" widget="float_time" string="Heure fin" />
                     <field name="totalhour"  widget="float_time"/>

                   </field>

        </field>
    </record>
```

when i want to add or redit a line i have this error:

```
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130205-000102\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\orm.py", line 3729, in _read_flat
KeyError: 53
```

Comment: will you please share full exception stack? That will give more idea about error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you define you function like this and check again:

```
def _total(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
    res = {}
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        res[record.id] =  record.hour_from + record.hour_to
    return res
```

or like this:

```
def _total(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
    res = {}
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        res[record.id] = {'totalhour' : 0.0}
        res[record.id]['totalhour'] = record.hour_from + record.hour_to
    return res
```

Regards,

Comment: Thank you very very  match it's work with the first function thak you again

Answer (score 0):

You can define your function like this:

```
def _total(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
    res = {}
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        res[record.id] = record.hour_from + record.hour_to
    return res
```

Here is the link for how to define functional fields, Hope this helpful for you.

http://doc.openerp.com/trunk/developers/server/03_module_dev_02/

Comment: thank you for your answer. it was halp mee and resolve some part of the probleme but i was **a new error** when i update my apps and i go to the view i have this error `Key error 9`