# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, xml, odoo

here is my error

```
2013-03-13 10:31:50,358 11345 ERROR OpenERP_DB openerp.osv.osv: Uncaught exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 131, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 197, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 185, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 4479, in create
    self.pool.get(object)._store_set_values(cr, user, ids, fields2, context)
  File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 4627, in _store_set_values
    result = self._columns[f].get(cr, self, ids, f, SUPERUSER_ID, context=context)
  File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 1137, in get
    elif result.get(id):
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'get'
2013-03-13 10:31:50,363 11345 ERROR OpenERP_DB openerp.netsvc: 'float' object has no attribute 'get'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/netsvc.py", line 293, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 618, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 188, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 131, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 197, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 185, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 4479, in create
    self.pool.get(object)._store_set_values(cr, user, ids, fields2, context)
  File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 4627, in _store_set_values
    result = self._columns[f].get(cr, self, ids, f, SUPERUSER_ID, context=context)
  File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 1137, in get
    elif result.get(id):
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'get'
2013-03-13 10:31:50,369 11345 INFO OpenERP_DB werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [13/Mar/2013 10:31:50] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

and here is my module source code

```
class namelistupdate(osv.osv):

    def _invoiced_rate(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context):
        amount_untaxed = 1
        if amount_untaxed == 0:
            res = 100.0
        else:
            res = 50.0
        print (res)
        return res

    _name = "checkroll.namelist.update"
    _description = "This table is for keeping Name list updates"
    _columns = {        
        'date': fields.date("Date"),
        'value': fields.function(_invoiced_rate, method=True, type='float', string='Test', store=True),
    }

namelistupdate()
```

i checked in backend table also.they correctly created and fileds also correctly manipulated.please check this and inform me whats the issue

here shows my view.xml file

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="namelist_update_form">
        <field name="name">Name List Update</field>
        <field name="model">checkroll.namelist.update</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="namelist_update">
                <field name="date" />
                <field name="value" />
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="namelist_update_list">
        <field name="name">Name List Update</field>
        <field name="model">checkroll.namelist.update</field>
        <field name="type">tree</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="namelist_update">
                <field name="value" />
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_namelist_update">
        <field name="name">Name List Update</field>
        <field name="res_model">checkroll.namelist.update</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>
```

Comment: error is clear enough you must be assigning a float value to `result` before doing `result.get(id)`, also can you show the code from where error is generated

Comment: @avasal: that's the problem, I think; that is inside the OpenERP package, so this could be a bug with that platform. Nothing in the OP code seems to indicate a cause.

Comment: I notice that `_invoiced_rate` is returning a float value. Perhaps it was expected to return a mapping instead?

Comment: thanks for yours earliest replies.i define res there.no related with any other parts.wrote this code because need to get idea about need to check how is the function fields work.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please check your function code. It's not like openerp function code.

Can you check this question link: [How add a function in openERP 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102388/how-add-a-function-in-openerp-7/15132719#15132719)

Answer (score 1):

```
def _invoiced_rate(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context):
    amount_untaxed = 1
    record_id=ids[0]
    res={record_id: 0.0}
    if amount_untaxed == 0:
        res[record_id] = 100.0
    else:
        res[record_id] = 50.0
    print (res)
    return res
```

I had need to return result in the form of dictionary object. and key should be id of that record.
Just replace My function

Credits need to go to Mr.Parth Gajjar @ http://help.openerp.com forum